# php finding file with relative but not with absolute path

Tags: php, image, file-exists, getimagesize

I wrote the following code and got the following result, but I don't understand why. I also don't know or find any solution to this online. Ideally I would like to have it work all four ways.

```
<?php
// Note: the file containing this script is located in
// "http://www.example.com/code.php" and the directories as
// listed below are all correct in relation to this script.

$link1 = "https://www.example.com/folder/image.png";
$link2 = "http://www.example.com/folder/image.png";
$link3 = "/folder/image.png";
$link4 = "folder/image.png";

var_dump(getimagesize($link1),file_exists($link1));
// returns bool(false) bool(false)

var_dump(getimagesize($link2),file_exists($link2));
// returns bool(false) bool(false)

var_dump(getimagesize($link3),file_exists($link3));
// returns bool(false) bool(false)

var_dump(getimagesize($link4),file_exists($link4));
// returns array(6) { [0]=> int(192) [1]=> int(250)
// [2]=> int(3) [3]=> string(24) "width="192" height="250""
// ["bits"]=> int(8) ["mime"]=> string(9) "image/png" }
// bool(true)

echo "<img src=\"$link1\" />";
echo "<img src=\"$link2\" />";
echo "<img src=\"$link3\" />";
echo "<img src=\"$link4\" />";
?>
```

In all four instances the image shows up properly using the `<img>` tag.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php is a pretty good start.

Comment: @Marcus I checked but on the page is an example with a full url (Example 3). It doesn't give more specifics there, so then I wonder why my example does not work.

Comment: Are you entering your *own* URL for testing? The URLs in the example (`example.com`) won't actually resolve. You need to replace those with your server address, eg. `http://www.**your-server**.com/**your_folder**/**your_image.png**`

Comment: @Marcus yes indeed I use my own server. I changed it for simplicity and anonymity reasons

Comment: So if you enter the value/URL of `$link1` and/or `$link2` directly into the browser address bar, you get the expected results? Eg. `image.png` display on the page?

Comment: @Marcus Correct -- see my latest edit of the question

Comment: Well, you might be having some `safe_mode` issues. Per the `file_exists()` doc: "*Warning
This function returns FALSE for files inaccessible due to safe mode restrictions. However these files still can be included if they are located in safe_mode_include_dir.*" That's the only other reason why `file_exists()` would return `false` that I can think of.

Comment: @Marcus Mhm... per what I know safe mode was removed in PHP Version 5.4. my server runs on PHP Version 5.6.20

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

`$link3` is not working because `file_exists()` is looking for `/folder/` all the way back to your root. `file_exists()` doesn't treat (relative) paths the same way the browser does.

So `file_exists('/folder/image.png')` isn't stemming off your *public* directory, it's rooting all the way back in the same fashion you would expect by entering in `/home/username/public_html/` or `/var/www/website/` know what I mean?

Entering in `file_exists('/path/to/your/public/dir/folder/image.png');` would work.

And `file_exists()` will always return false if trying to add an `http://` link to your asset in question. It only resolves absolute paths in the server directory path structure.

Comment: I am just editing my question. The directory is correct, and I tried all four links and the picture can be found there.